# Finding $\sigma$-algebra for given its generator.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=\{1,a,b,c\}$, $Y=\{2,A,BC\}$ be 2 sets, and let $f:X\to Y$  be a function such that: $f(1)=2$, $f(a)=A$, and $f(b)=f(c)=BC$. We have a collection  $\mathcal{G}=\{\underbrace{\{2\}}_{\textrm{set}~ G_1}, \underbrace{\{2,BC\}}_{\textrm{set}~ G_2}\}$. How can we find the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{G}$, which is usually symbolized as $\sigma(\mathcal{G})$.

One gave me the following answer but I am not sure about it
\begin{align}
%\displaybreak
\sigma(\mathcal{G}) &=
\left\{
  \begin{array}{c}
    Y, \{\varnothing\}, \\
    G_1, G_2, G_1^c, G_2^c, \\
    G_1\cup G_2, (G_1\cup G_2)^c
  \end{array}
\right\}.
\end{align}

Can anyone help me please?
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct. You can prove it is correct by showing:

1. That the listed answer is indeed a $\sigma$-algebra
2. That any $\sigma$-algebra containing $G$ must also contain $G_1,G_2,G_1^c,G_2^c,G_1\cup G_2$ and $(G_1\cup G_2)^c$.

Comment: Dear @5xum, I do not understand why $\sigma(\mathcal{G})$ includes the set $Y$. Would you mind explaining this clearly? Best.

Comment: @pej First of all, $\sigma(G)$ does *NOT* unclude $\{\emptyset\}$, it includes $\emptyset$. Second of all, it also includes all complements of all sets, including the empty set. And it includes $Y$ by definition.